# How to make play and pause button on Augmented Reality (Vuforia) video playback in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

There is a problem on my project that when it plays the video play automatically. How I want to make the video play and pause in Unity. I'm using Unity 2019.3.5f1 and Vuforia. Is there any tutorial about how to make video playback AR can play and pause?

I try this code but it doesn't work. I don't know why?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class PlayControl : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    public GameObject videoplayer, Playvideo_button, Pausevideo_button, Stopvideo_button;

    protected TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {

            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");

            if (mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName == "Video_marker")
            {
                videoplayer.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Play();
            }
            OnTrackingFound();
        }
        else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED &&
                  newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
            videoplayer.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Stop();
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
        else
        {
            // For combo of previousStatus=UNKNOWN + newStatus=UNKNOWN|NOT_FOUND
            // Vuforia is starting, but tracking has not been lost or found yet
            // Call OnTrackingLost() to hide the augmentations
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if(mTrackableBehaviour)
            {
              mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
            }
    }

    protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Enable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = true;
    }


    protected virtual void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Disable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {

                //case 1
                if (hit.collider.tag == "Playvideo")
                {
                    videoplayer.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Play();
                    Playvideo_button.SetActive(false);
                    Pausevideo_button.SetActive(true);
                    Stopvideo_button.SetActive(true);
                }

                //case 2
                if (hit.collider.tag == "Stopvideo")
                {
                    videoplayer.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Stop();
                    Playvideo_button.SetActive(true);
                    Pausevideo_button.SetActive(true);
                    Stopvideo_button.SetActive(false);
                }

                //case 3
                if (hit.collider.tag == "Pausevideo")
                {
                    videoplayer.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Pause();
                    Playvideo_button.SetActive(true);
                    Pausevideo_button.SetActive(false);
                    Stopvideo_button.SetActive(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Done edit adding code

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear where does this script runs in your project. The best way to make sure your hits are in the right place is to add the script to the buttons, which I see that you didn't. Did you make sure your Raycast reaches the right button? you can define a `maxDistance` to your `Physics.Raycast` that may be a great help here. Also in your "if" statements, I would check if there is a collision first and then check for the tag, something like this:

```
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 900.0f))
        {
            if (hit.transform != null)
                {
                        if (GameObject.ReferenceEquals(hit.transform.gameObject, playButtonGameObject))
                            {
                                videoplayer.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Play();
                                Playvideo_button.SetActive(false);
                                Pausevideo_button.SetActive(true);
                                Stopvideo_button.SetActive(true);
                            }
                        else if (GameObject.ReferenceEquals(hit.transform.gameObject, stopButtonGameObject))
                            {
                                videoplayer.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Stop();
                                Playvideo_button.SetActive(true);
                                Pausevideo_button.SetActive(true);
                                Stopvideo_button.SetActive(false);
                            }
                        else if (GameObject.ReferenceEquals(hit.transform.gameObject, pauseButtonGameObject))
                            {
                                videoplayer.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>().Pause();
                                Playvideo_button.SetActive(true);
                                Pausevideo_button.SetActive(false);
                                Stopvideo_button.SetActive(true);
                            }
                }
        }
```